# Check whether an embeded youtube video has started

Tags: html, youtube, youtube-api

I have a script for embedded YouTube video.

Here's my script

```
<object width="500" height="375">
    <param name="movie" 
               value="http://www.youtube.com/v/mLDTfRDM_LE?version=3&autohide=1&showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1">
        </param>
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
        </param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/mLDTfRDM_LE?version=3&autohide=1&autoplay=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&enablejsapi=1" 
               type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
               allowscriptaccess="always" 
               width="500" height="375">
        </embed> 
        </object>
```

Now I want to check whether the video has started or not, and based on that I want to alert:

```
"Hii video has started"
```

There is a similar link like this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215658/checking-whether-an-embedded-youtube-video-has-started

but I have a different script.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is like this:

1) You'll need to put an id attribute on the `<embed>` element -- this will allow you to listen to the player events. You'll need it in the next step. This example assumes the embed id is 'myPlayer'

2) Include this script on your page, just before closing the body:

```
<script>
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
        ytplayer = document.getElementById("myPlayer");
        ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
}

function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
        if (newState=="1") {
                alert("Hii video has started");
        }
}
</script>
```

The `onYouTubePlayerReady` function is automatically run when the player is loaded and ready to go; this script will set up a listener at that time, and if it hears a state change event telling you that the video is playing, it will do the alert you desire.

Note a few really important things. This method is often inconsistent on IE -- you could append this as an attribute to the object element:

```
classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
```

But a much, much better solution would be to not use the static embed code, but instead to use SWFObject. Follow this documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Examples

Another possibility, if you use jQuery, is the tubePlayer plugin: http://www.tikku.com/jquery-youtube-tubeplayer-plugin

Of course, my biggest recommendation would be to not use an AS3 embed at all, but instead use an iFrame: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference